# How to run an AngularJS function against model before the filter is invoked?

Tags: angularjs

This is a simple filter :

http://jsfiddle.net/yctchgnk/69/

I'm attempting to run an AngularJS function before the filter is invoked.
But the ng-change event is not being fired. How to run an AngularJS function against model before the filter is invoked ?

src :

```
<input ng-change="changed" type="text" ng-model="search">
<ul ng-repeat="oneauth in authorisations | search">
{{entry.auth.name}}
</ul>

var app = angular.module('myapp', [], function () {});

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.authorisations = [
        {
            "auth":{
                "number":"453",
                "name":"Apple Inc."
            }
        },
        {
            "auth":{
                "number":"123",
                "name":"Microsoft Inc."
             }
    }];

    $scope.changed = function(){
        alert('changed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
<input ng-change="changed" type="text" ng-model="search">
```

with

```
<input ng-change="changed()" type="text" ng-model="search">
```

Hope it works.!

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1)
Specify filter in ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="oneauth in authorisations | filter : search"
```

2)
Specify function in ng-change:

```
ng-change="changed()"
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s80a6mm0/)